# Kibana composite query pagination

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite, vega

I have a composite aggregation query doing exactly what I want (the details of said query should not matter). I would like very much to visualise the results in Vega as a nice time-based chart, but I've hit a very stupid roadblock: I cannot find how to ask Vega to fetch all results. Composite aggregation results are paged (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_pagination) and therefore, in order to get all results, multiple queries should be done. So I can display one page of data, which is not enough in my case.

Is there a way to fetch all pages with Vega or Vega-Lite? If not, perhaps in another graph module of Kibana? A quick search gave no definitive answers… And finally, I have the latest version of everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, no. Dynamic elastic URLs are not doable (basing a query of another query), I think I put through a feature request for this a while back, but unfortunately Vega and Kibana integrations get pushed to the way side for improvements in Lens.

Hopefully in the future this is something they do because it would severely improve the Vega-Kibana capibilities. I guess it depends on what you are actually trying to do, and whether you can find a way to get the data through in one search - this would be my advice.